# How to solve for "TypeError: must be real number, not MulExpression" while solving optimization problem using CVXPY?

Tags: python, optimization, minimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I was trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$\begin{array}{l}
\min \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\left{ {\log [1 + \exp ({\theta ^T}{u^i})] + [1 - {v^i}{\theta ^T}{u^i}]} \right}} \
U \in {R^{3X10}},V \in {R^{10}},\theta  \in {R^4}
\end{array}$

My constraints  are 0 <= U(i,1)*x <= 0, i=1 to N.

I have written the code as follows:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import math as mp
N=10
U_size=3
V_size=1
n=U_size+V_size
u_i=np.ones((N,1))
Gen_U_1_3= np.random.randint(low=0,high=6,size=(N, n-1))
Gen_V_4= np.random.randint(low=0,high=2,size=(N, 1))
Gen_U_V= np.concatenate((Gen_U_1_3,Gen_V_4),axis=1)
U=np.concatenate((u_i,Gen_U_1_3),axis=1)
V=Gen_V_4

x = cp.Variable(n)
#objective function
sum=0
for i in range(N):
    sum +=mp.log(1+mp.exp(x.T@U[i,:].T))+(1-(V[i,:]@x.T@U[i,:].T))
    
const =[(U[i,:]@x<=1, U[i,:]@x>=0) for i in range(N) ]
 
# Construct the problem.
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(sum),
                  const )
prob.solve()
result = prob.solve()
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\demo_optimization_1.py", line 19, in <module>
    sum +=mp.log(1+mp.exp(x.T@U[i,:].T))+(1-(V[i,:]@x.T@U[i,:].T))  
TypeError: must be real number, not MulExpression
```

I am new to python. I tried to solve this error but could do this so far. Can anyone suggest what is wrong with the expression of the Objective function?

Comment: I think this is about `mp.exp` and `mp.log` not knowing about cvxpy constructs, The available functions in cvxpy are listed here: https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html. Those are the ones you need to use.

Comment: I am trying to run your code and encountered a bunch of problems. So, as Erwin said you need to change your `Obj Func` expression. `cvxpy` has built in functions and you can use them.
Additionally, your constraints do not seem to be working out the way you wrote them. Please edit your question with the numerical expression of your optimization problem so I can find the faulty part. With the current information, it's hard to catch your error.

Comment: For X >= 0 and X <= 1, you should have two separate constraints and then concatenate them. The way you defined is not recognized by cvxpy.

Comment: @HadiRohani I edited the objective function. I am still trying but same error.

Comment: You are still using `mp.exp` and `mp.log`. As said earlier: that does not work.